# Use different impl when type parameters are the same

Tags: rust, typenum

I have an impl with two generic `typenum` parameters. The impl's function should return a different type when the parameters are the same. (The different type is a more compact representation that can only be realized when the type parameters are the same.) Is it possible to use a different impl based on type equality? The naive method below produces a "conflicting implementations" error because Rust does not take the more specific implementation.

```
extern crate typenum;
use typenum::Unsigned;

use std::ops::Mul;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Matrix<N: Unsigned, M: Unsigned> {
    n: usize,
    m: usize,
    elements: Vec<f64>,
    _marker: PhantomData<(N, M)>
}

// The more compact representation
struct SquareMatrix<N: Unsigned> {
    n: usize,
    elements: Vec<f64>,
    _marker: PhantomData<(N)>
}

impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned, M: Unsigned> Mul<Matrix<D, M>> for Matrix<N, D> {
    type Output = Matrix<N, M>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<D, M>) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

// The more specific implementation
impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned> Mul<Matrix<D, N>> for Matrix<N, D> {
    type Output = SquareMatrix<N>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<D, N>) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) (which is still unstable as of Rust 1.16.0), you can. Basically, all you need is to declare the items in the more general implementation with `default` to say "this can be specialized".

```
#![feature(specialization)]

impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned, M: Unsigned> Mul<Matrix<D, M>> for Matrix<N, D> {
    default type Output = Matrix<N, M>;

    default fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<D, M>) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

// The more specific implementation
impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned> Mul<Matrix<D, N>> for Matrix<N, D> {
    type Output = SquareMatrix<N>;

    fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<D, N>) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is just no end to the good stuff one can find behind a Rust feature gate.

Comment: Where can I find documentation for `specialization`? It's not listed [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/attributes.html#compiler-features) or [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#compiler-features); is there somewhere else I should be looking to see a list of available/possible `feature`s?

Comment: The best documentation on specialization at this time is probably the RFC I linked to. The lack of documentation for new features is a [known problem](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1636-document_all_features.md). An exhaustive list of the available compiler features probably only exists in the compiler's source code.

Comment: This doesn't work. Specialization does not currently work with associated types, and as far as I know, it is an open question as to whether it ever will.

Comment: @paholg: Can you elaborate? When you multiply a `Matrix<N, D>` by a `Matrix<D, N>`, the result type is indeed `SquareMatrix<N>`, which shows that specialization works with associated types. However, I am noticing now that trying to multiply a `Matrix<N, D>` by a `Matrix<D, M>` gives a compiler error (expected `N`, found `M`). It looks like the compiler is trying to use the specialized implementation even though it doesn't apply. But removing `default` on the associated type doesn't fix the problem, so the problem is not related to associated types.

Comment: @FrancisGagné [The tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) shows it as a question still, and I was under the impression that it was never answered or implemented, but I may be operating on outdated information. I had run a quick test, and verified it didn't work without looking too closely. This behavior does seem very strange; the specific implementation works, and removing the specific implementation makes the default one work, even with the default keywords still there. On second look, it seems to just ignore the default impl when the specialized one exists.

Comment: @FrancisGagné I have managed to get simplified code to exhibit this bug [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=255df3d3853a9c428c7658cb5c2a199c&version=nightly&backtrace=0). You're right, it has nothing to do with the associated types.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in stable Rust right now, it just requires some extra boiler-plate.

First, we will create an internal multiplication trait that will do the actual work:

```
pub trait MulPrivate<Rhs, AreEqual> {
    type Output;
    fn mul_private(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}
```

Note the extra type parameter: This is how we will differentiate the two cases.

Then, we make our regular `Mul` implementation call out to this internal one:

```
use typenum::{IsEqual, Eq};
impl<N, M, D> Mul<Matrix<D, M>> for Matrix<N, D>
    where D: Unsigned,
          M: Unsigned,
          N: Unsigned + IsEqual<M>,
          Matrix<N, D>: MulPrivate<Matrix<D, M>, Eq<N, M>>,
{
    type Output = <Matrix<N, D> as MulPrivate<Matrix<D, M>, Eq<N, M>>>::Output;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<D, M>) -> Self::Output {
        self.mul_private(rhs)
    }
}
```

This allows us to compare `N` and `M`. If they are equal, that extra type parameter will be `True`, otherwise it will be `False`. Now we are free to make the two different implementations of `MulPrivate`:

```
use typenum::{True, False};
impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned, M: Unsigned> MulPrivate<Matrix<D, M>, False> for Matrix<N, D> {
    type Output = Matrix<N, M>;
    fn mul_private(self, rhs: Matrix<D, M>) -> Self::Output {
        println!("not square!");
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

// The more specific implementation
impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned> MulPrivate<Matrix<D, N>, True> for Matrix<N, D> {
    type Output = SquareMatrix<N>;
    fn mul_private(self, rhs: Matrix<D, N>) -> Self::Output {
        println!("square!");
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

---

Note that once [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20400) is resolved, you will be able to get rid of all of this boilerplate and can write it as:

```
impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned, M: Unsigned> Mul<Matrix<D, M>> for Matrix<N, D> where N: IsEqual<M, Output = False> {
    type Output = Matrix<N, M>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<D, M>) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

// The more specific implementation
impl<N: Unsigned, D: Unsigned> Mul<Matrix<D, N>> for Matrix<N, D> where N: IsEqual<N, Output = True>  {
    type Output = SquareMatrix<N>;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Matrix<D, N>) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```