# Override trait implementation when two type parameters are the same?

Tags: rust

I have a struct with two type parameters, and a trait:

```
struct MyStruct<T1, T2>{
    field1: T1,
    field2: T2,
}
trait ToList<T>{
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T>;
}
```

I want to implement my trait on this struct, but if the structs type parameters are equal, I have a "stronger" implementation I want to use:

```
impl <T> ToList<T> for MyStruct<T, T>
    {
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T>{
        vec![self.field1, self.field2]
    }
}
impl <T1, T2> ToList<T1> for MyStruct<T1, T2>
    {
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T1>{
        vec![self.field1]
    }
}
```

Note that the first implementation is only valid if the types are the same.

Either of the above implementations will compile, but if I try to define both, they conflict. I've been trying to follow the instructions from [Use different impl when type parameters are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021272/use-different-impl-when-type-parameters-are-the-same), but that follows a much more complicated use case. Eventually I hit two walls:

- (Less importantly) the compiler doesn't seem to recognize that if `IsEqual<T1, T2>::Output = True`, this implies that `T1` and `T2` are the same (not sure if it's supposed to and I can work around that)
- (More importantly) `TypeNum::IsEqual` does not seem to be implemented for anything, at least not in a way my compiler can see.

```
use typenum::{IsEqual, True, False};

fn main() {
    let struct1 = MyStruct{field1: 1, field2: 2};
    let struct2 = MyStruct{field1: 1, field2: true};
    let list1  = struct1.to_list();
    let list2 = struct2.to_list();
    println!("{:?}", list1);
    println!("{:?}", list2);
}

struct MyStruct<T1, T2>{
    field1: T1,
    field2: T2,
}
trait ToList<T, AreEqual>{
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T>;
}

impl <T> ToList<T, True> for MyStruct<T, T> 
    {
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T>{
        vec![self.field1, self.field2]
    }
}
impl <T1, T2> ToList<T1, False> for MyStruct<T1, T2>
    where T2: IsEqual<T1, Output=False>,
    {
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T1>{
        vec![self.field1]
    }
}
```

This does not compile because with an error on the second `to_list()` call:

```
the method `to_list` exists for struct `MyStruct<{integer}, bool>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
method cannot be called on `MyStruct<{integer}, bool>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
main.rs(12, 1): method `to_list` not found for this struct
main.rs(12, 1): doesn't satisfy `MyStruct<{integer}, bool>: ToList<{integer}, B0>`
main.rs(27, 27): the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
`<bool as IsEqual<{integer}>>::Output = B0`
```

I did eventually find that if I wrap `bool` and `i32` in my own wrapper types and implement `IsEqual` on the wrappers I can make this compile, but to use that more broadly I'd have to write specific wrappers for every combination of types I intend to use.

Is there something I'm missing to make the `typenum` approach work, or is there an entirely different/simpler route I should be taking?

EDIT: The below shows how this can work if I provide an `impl` for the `IsEqual` trait. (I have to use `Wrapped` because I'm unable to implement it directly on externally defined types.)

```
use typenum::{IsEqual, True, False};

struct Wrapped<T>(T);

fn main() {
    let struct1 = MyStruct{field1: 1, field2: 2};
    let struct2: MyStruct<i32, bool>      = MyStruct{field1: 1, field2: true};
    let list1  = struct1.to_list();
    let list2 = struct2.to_list();
    println!("{:?}", list1);
    println!("{:?}", list2);
}

struct MyStruct<T1, T2>{
    field1: T1,
    field2: T2,
}
trait ToList<T, AreEqual>{
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T>;
}

impl <T> ToList<T, True> for MyStruct<T, T> 
    {
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T>{
        vec![self.field1, self.field2]
    }
}
impl <T1, T2> ToList<T1, False> for MyStruct<T1, T2>
    where Wrapped<T2>: IsEqual<Wrapped<T1>, Output=False>,
    {
    fn to_list(self) -> Vec<T1>{
        vec![self.field1]
    }
}

impl IsEqual<Wrapped<i32>> for Wrapped<bool>{
    type Output = False;
    fn is_equal(self, rhs: Wrapped<i32>) -> Self::Output {
        todo!()
    }
}
impl IsEqual<Wrapped<i32>> for Wrapped<i32>{
    type Output = True;
    fn is_equal(self, rhs: Wrapped<i32>) -> Self::Output {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is classic [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844), that Rust doesn't have, and even with specialization somewhere in the future stabilized (if ever), this case will probably be never stabilized, since it is unsound to specialize like that.

So no, you cannot do that in Rust.

*Iff* you don't need to work in generic code, but only when the concrete types are known, you can use the more limited [autoref specialization](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/tree/master/autoref-specialization).

Comment: I'm confused by this, because what I have is very close to working - it seems to only be the missing impl of `IsEqual`. As mentioned, if I provide such an implementation with an appropriate `Output` type for some pair of types, that works.

Comment: I added the working implementation into my question.

Comment: @EdwardPeters Yes, but solving this problem of "I have to add an `impl` for each type" is basically having to solve specialization again from the beginning. You need an associated type to be `True` when types are equal and `False` when they're unequal - that's the same problem in a different form. You just added a level of indirection, which, contrary to a popular belief, doesn't _always_ solves all problems.

Comment: That makes sense, but isn't part of the point of the `typenum` crate to provide some blanket implementations over at least simple types? I get lost trying to follow the crate's source code, but there's a bunch of generic implementations backed by some macro code.. Is it possible I'm just failing to properly import some needed trait or implementation?

Comment: @EdwardPeters `typenum` is definitely not made for specialization, it advises itself as "type-level numbers evaluated at compile time". It is meant as a replacement to const generics. The `IsEqual` trait is meant to compare integers at compile time.

Comment: I messed around with this some more, and got something that's like halfway there - it doesn't give type comparison for free, but it lets you make comparisons over any types you've associated with an index from `typenum`. (In another answer if you're curious or have warnings)

Answer (score 0):

So while @Chayim Friedman's answer is correct in general, I did find an extremely hacky partial workaround:

```
use typenum::*;

trait Indexed {
    type Index: Integer;
}
impl Indexed for bool {
    type Index = N1;
}
impl Indexed for usize {
    type Index = N10;
}

trait IndexedEqual<T1> {
    type IsEqual;
}
impl<T0, T1> IndexedEqual<T1> for T0
where
    T0: Indexed,
    T1: Indexed,
    <T0 as Indexed>::Index: IsEqual<<T1 as Indexed>::Index>,
{
    type IsEqual = <<T0 as Indexed>::Index as IsEqual<<T1 as Indexed>::Index>>::Output;
}

trait Specialized<T1, True> {
    fn print_sameness(&self, other: T1);
}
impl<T0, T1> Specialized<T1, True> for T0
where
    T0: IndexedEqual<T1, IsEqual = True>,
{
    fn print_sameness(&self, other: T1) {
        println!("They're the same");
    }
}
impl<T0, T1> Specialized<T1, False> for T0
where
    T0: IndexedEqual<T1, IsEqual = False>,
{
    fn print_sameness(&self, other: T1) {
        println!("They're different");
    }
}

fn main() {
    false.print_sameness(true);
    1.print_sameness(0);
    0.print_sameness(true);
    false.print_sameness(1);
}
```

Essentially, while the `typenum` crate isn't intended to provide specialization, it does provide a large number of types over which type-level equality checks can be performed. If you want to distinguish that *certain* types are the same or different, this can be achieved by:

- Relating each type to an `Integer` using the `Indexed` trait above
- Creating a specialized trait with a "Boolean" type parameter
- Implementing the trait with different behavior and a different value of the tag, based on comparisons from `IndexedEqual` above.

This is probably a very bad idea, but it's here if you want it.